# How to add a row to a DBGrid?

Tags: delphi

How to add a line to a DBGrid by code?

i like to add the line of my excel worm DBGrid

```
c := 'A';
while(c<='Z') do
begin
  test1 := (Sheet.Range\[c+'1'\].value)   ;
  if (test1 <> '' ) then
  begin
    nbr := nbr + 1 ;
    Col:=DBGrid1.Columns.Add;
    Col.Title.Caption:=test1;
    byte(c) := byte(c)+1;
  end
  else
    byte(c) := byte(c)+1;
end ;
```

Comment: Hi. Welcome to S.O. Please explain the question with more information. The title does not correspond to the code and the explanation is very basic. Spend time on the question to get a better answer.

Comment: Despite your q title asking how to add a **row** to a dbgrid, your code doesn't do that, but insteads attempts to add a **column** to the dbgrid.  As you have been told in @No'amNewman's answer, the way to add a **row** to a dbgrid is to add a data row to the grid's dataset.  You can do that by calling DataSet.InsertRecord and other methods.  You need to clarify your q, meanwhile I'm voting to close it.

Answer (score 2):

One doesn't add a row to a DBGrid: one adds the data to the underlying dataset. Maybe you meant to use TGrid.

Comment: no bdgrid i display the columns acv this code but now i need to display the line so there are two nested loops but the data recovery structure does not lconne